# Using FPDF with specific contact form 7 forms

Tags: php, wordpress, fpdf, contact-form-7

I'm using the solution listed here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/convert-form-output-to-pdf-attachment to create a pdf using form data with fpdf and contact form 7 on a Wordpress build.

Does anyone know how to attach the pdf to one particular form?

This solution works great but it seems to attach the pdf to all contact 7 forms. Is there a way to have it only attach to a specific form for those of us that have multiple forms on one site. Maybe by form id?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have solved it. Used the following variable and if statement.

$id = $contact_form->id();

if ($id==16) *where 16 equals the id of the contact 7 form*

There's probably more efficient solutions but I'm not proficient in PHP.